# How to reboot W2K8 server if I've got a "zombie" console window?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a problem.. Due to a bug in FAR Manager I've got a "zombie" console window on W2K8.. I can't close this window, and I can't find "far.exe" in system process list to kill it manually (see this picture: http://sergeypopov.info/_misc/zombie-console-window-2.png).

And I can't reboot server, all my attempts was failed with a message "The attempt by user XYZ\XYZ to restart/shutdown computer XYZ failed" in Event Log.

Unfortunately, I haven't psychical access to the server right now..

How can I force the server to reboot? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Killing my winlogon process helps me.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the command prompt

shutdown -r

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work..

Comment: shutdown /r /f /t 5

Comment: Thank you, but shutdown utility DOESN’T WORK with ANY arguments because it initiates a "normal" shutdown process, not "emergency".

Comment: Nevertheless, I solved my problem. I wrote a small utility and called NtShutdownSystem() directly. So, server was rebooted without any stupid questions, timeouts etc.